# Ignorar alinhamento de coluna em flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou tentando colocar uma coluna dentro de outra coluna, mas gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de ignorar o primeiro alinhamento, como no código abaixo:

```
class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Create an account")
              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Como o meu Widget Text está dentro de uma Column principal centralizada, não consigo aplicar o MainAxisAlignment.end.

Gostaria de forçar o o Widget para a bottom position.

Comment: Coloca os dois como end, mas se não tem mais nada dentro do segundo Column usa só um e coloca como end.

Comment: O que esta acontecendo é que ele deve esta alinhado ao final mas como o outro esta ao centro ele esta preenchendo. Coloca o crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, do interno.

Comment: Põe o Text dentro de um Container e alinha a direita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é sua coluna sem tamanho, então ela se ajusta ao conteúdo dos filhos (`childrens`).

Neste caso, você deve setar um tamanho, ou expandir dinamicamente.

---

#### Resolvendo

Uma opção, seria o `Expanded`, veja no exemplo em seu código:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[Text("Create an account")],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

#### Links úteis

Documentação oficial: [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

Esse vídeo é muito bom: [Flutter Layouts Walkthrough: Row, Column, Stack, Expanded, Padding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJEnTRBxaSg)